# Unable to access object properties with dot notation in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an object that is being passed a prop `playerSystem` from one component to the other.
This is `playerSystem` logged to the console.

```
sector: {
{
cords: "A-6450"
systemName: "A-79672"
systemPlanets: (8) ['Ocean', 'Rocky', 'Gas', 'Temperate', 'Gas', 'Frozen', 'Lava', 'Frozen']
systemStar: "Red-Dwarf"
}
}
```

This is being logged to the console so I know there is not a problem with the data.
I want to access the inner object of `sector` with the properties like `systemName`, so I am trying to do that

```
 useEffect(() => {
        console.log(playerSystem.systemName)
        console.log(playerSystem.sector)
    }, [])
```

Both of these throw the same error, `Property 'systemName'/'sector' does not exist on type 'Object'.`

How can I access the nested properties of my object?

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you console.log `playerSystem`?

Comment: The first block of code is the log of `playersystem`, apologies for not being clear.

Comment: So, this should be `playerSystem.sector.systemName`, not `playerSystem.systemName`. Right?
Your `playerSystem` is not correct syntax, why is it have double `{` in `sector`?

Comment: I've tried that as well, and it still throws an error under `sector`

Comment: Can you parse your code into codesanbox.io ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-resonance-dsw9fw 
This error is in the `system-view` component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244977/discussion-between-mikenlanggio-and-imstupidpleasehelp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone sees this in the future. My issue was that my object was actually an array. It was `[{data.subdata}]` So i was unable to use dot notation unless I did `data[0].subdata`

Answer (score 0):

You have to dependent `playerSystem` into `useEffect`

```
 useEffect(() => {
        console.log(playerSystem.systemName)
        console.log(playerSystem.sector)
    }, [playerSystem])
```

Comment: I'm still not able to access the properties of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Try representing the type of playerSystem prop that a component is receiving, only then ts will be able to know the properties that exist on that object.

```
type sectorType = {
 systemStar: string,
 systemPlanets: string[],
 systemName: string,
 cords: string
};
interface playerSystemProps {
  playerSystem: sectorType;
  setPlayerSystem: Function;
}
```